# Python Requests POST DATA Error 400 Header name invalid

Tags: python, request, http2, http-status-code-400

I want to send a post data requests to this URL : https://www.createsend.com/t/securedsubscribe?token=" + token Every time the token is changing but i figure out a way to retrieve it. But i can't acces the internet site

When i check in Chrome Console this header is used.

```
authority:www.createsend.com
method:POST
path:/t/securedsubscribe?token=7B9BCC9AE0CD58E2170E07A7D79E679426EBC1D02FA06CA791557CA7ACC1155F5A0DDA83D987E06C
scheme:https
accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:fr
cache-control:max-age=0
content-length:174
content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
cookie:__utma=38149500.1167947680.1522060606.1522060606.1522060606.1; __utmc=38149500; __utmz=38149500.1522060606.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); __utmt=1; _ga=GA1.2.1167947680.1522060606; _gid=GA1.2.485326558.1522060607; ajs_group_id=null; __qca=P0-314313712-1522060607057; mp_mixpanel__c=0; ajs_user_id=%22C5EC08CADFFC107B-B6DC4E4B6840339E%22; ajs_anonymous_id=%222e3961d1-be64-4ecf-8481-c8a47295b130%22; __utmv=38149500.|1=user-type=user=1; __utmb=38149500.2.10.1522060606; mp_1c1eda798f92601aecaa904fe7b3520a_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%22C5EC08CADFFC107B-B6DC4E4B6840339E%22%2C%22mp_lib%22%3A%20%22Segment%3A%20web%22%2C%22%24search_engine%22%3A%20%22google%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.be%2F%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22www.google.be%22%2C%22mp_name_tag%22%3A%20%22C5EC08CADFFC107B-B6DC4E4B6840339E%22%2C%22id%22%3A%20%22C5EC08CADFFC107B-B6DC4E4B6840339E%22%7D; _uetsid=_uetcde93ba3; optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1522060693722r0.545521542891791; optimizelyBuckets=%7B%7D; optimizelySegments=%7B%22341521689%22%3A%22direct%22%2C%22341576276%22%3A%22gc%22%2C%22341588087%22%3A%22false%22%2C%222833930025%22%3A%22none%22%2C%225027931715%22%3A%22true%22%2C%225195510267%22%3A%22true%22%7D; intercom-lou-je5td1qt=1; intercom-session-je5td1qt=WmxjSDdDVlRYYTZUc1Z3bmlENTNhOXFJUzhvK2piZElBakFjbDI5dkpwS0hvWEFLVmMweWNHNER0Ujh3QTFKUy0tdGt0aitQQTNuQWoxZGhXMUllakhMQT09--ec3c7db367f57a30eb5b5818de90e43dc8cc39a6; __ssid=089a6e70-58c2-41bb-98d2-90ce7ada1d73
origin:http://tres-bien.com
referer:http://tres-bien.com/odehhasoidj
upgrade-insecure-requests:1
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/64.0.3282.167 Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36
```

This webpage use H2 protocole. So i use Hyper module to pass trough :

```
session.mount("https://www.createsend.com",HTTP20Adapter())
r = session.post(url , data=payload2 , headers=header2)
print(r.text)
```

But I still get this error.

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Header</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

The website's form I'm submitting : http://tres-bien.com/odehhasoidj where you can check which POST requests are made

This is my code

```
header2 = {
#'Host': 'www.createsend.com',
'authority':'www.createsend.com' ,
'method':'POST',
'path':'/t/securedsubscribe?token=' + token,
'scheme':'https',
'accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
'accept-encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language':'fr',
'cache-control':'max-age=0',
#'content-length':'182',
'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'origin':'http://tres-bien.com',
'referer':'http://tres-bien.com/odehhasoidj',
'upgrade-insecure-requests':'1',
#'cookie':'__utma=38149500.1167947680.1522060606.1522060606.1522060606.1; __utmc=38149500; __utmz=38149500.1522060606.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); __utmt=1; _ga=GA1.2.1167947680.1522060606; _gid=GA1.2.485326558.1522060607; ajs_group_id=null; __qca=P0-314313712-1522060607057; mp_mixpanel__c=0; ajs_user_id=%22C5EC08CADFFC107B-B6DC4E4B6840339E%22; ajs_anonymous_id=%222e3961d1-be64-4ecf-8481-c8a47295b130%22; __utmv=38149500.|1=user-type=user=1; __utmb=38149500.2.10.1522060606; mp_1c1eda798f92601aecaa904fe7b3520a_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%22C5EC08CADFFC107B-B6DC4E4B6840339E%22%2C%22mp_lib%22%3A%20%22Segment%3A%20web%22%2C%22%24search_engine%22%3A%20%22google%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.be%2F%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22www.google.be%22%2C%22mp_name_tag%22%3A%20%22C5EC08CADFFC107B-B6DC4E4B6840339E%22%2C%22id%22%3A%20%22C5EC08CADFFC107B-B6DC4E4B6840339E%22%7D; _uetsid=_uetcde93ba3; optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1522060693722r0.545521542891791; optimizelyBuckets=%7B%7D; optimizelySegments=%7B%22341521689%22%3A%22direct%22%2C%22341576276%22%3A%22gc%22%2C%22341588087%22%3A%22false%22%2C%222833930025%22%3A%22none%22%2C%225027931715%22%3A%22true%22%2C%225195510267%22%3A%22true%22%7D; intercom-lou-je5td1qt=1; intercom-session-je5td1qt=WmxjSDdDVlRYYTZUc1Z3bmlENTNhOXFJUzhvK2piZElBakFjbDI5dkpwS0hvWEFLVmMweWNHNER0Ujh3QTFKUy0tdGt0aitQQTNuQWoxZGhXMUllakhMQT09--ec3c7db367f57a30eb5b5818de90e43dc8cc39a6; __ssid=089a6e70-58c2-41bb-98d2-90ce7ada1d73',
#'Authorization': token ,
'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/64.0.3282.167 Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36'
}

payload2 = {

'cm-name' : 'Namz Foll' ,
'cm-zlutdu-zlutdu' : email ,
'cm-f-qkytli': 'Adress Bilning' ,
'cm-f-qkytld': '1030' ,
'cm-f-qkytlh': 'Ciky' ,
'cm-fo-qkytlk ' : '3324398' ,
'cm-f-qkytlu' : '0412345408' ,
'cm-fo-qkytry' : '3324639'

}
url = "https://www.createsend.com/t/securedsubscribe?token=" + token
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information to tell, but `authority`, `scheme`, etc. are *special* headers that must be prefixed by a colon, as in `:authority`, `:scheme`, etc.

Please see "Pseudo Header Fields" here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.

Comment: Thank you , even tough it's not working even with colon I'm looking into it !

Answer (score 0):

This header belongs to HTTP/2. And you can't use them with requests library, but you can use another library [hyper](https://hyper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
from hyper import HTTPConnection

conn = HTTPConnection('http2bin.org:443')
conn.request('GET', '/get')
resp = conn.get_response()

print(resp.read())
```

But learning a new library can be a time taking process, and as we know requests us much simple, to know how you can use this header, this [link](http://www.thefirstcode.com/how-to-use-python-requests-library-with-http2) has explained it very well.